# Problems processing an XML file

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm using JQuery to retrieve an XML file.  The XML file is dynamically generated (PHP) based upon parameters passed to it with JQuery.  So for example, I request information on three IDs (in this example: 0ZJB001, 5YH043, 9TQ987).  The returned XML file contains a list of the requested IDs and the found items.  I'm then changing span contents depending upon these values.  I've got this working fine, except when less items are returned than requested.  So, if three items are requested and only two are returned, the JQuery each statement is only executed twice.  Instead, I need it to execute for each ItemId and retrieve details from the corresponding ASIN Item, or otherwise update with some default details.

Sample XML file format (not exact, it's simplified):

```
<ItemLookupResponse>
    <Items>
        <Request>
            <ItemLookupRequest>
                <ItemId>0ZJB001</ItemId>
                <ItemId>5YH043</ItemId>
                <ItemId>9TQ987</ItemId>
                <VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
            </ItemLookupRequest>
        </Request>
        <Item>
            <ASIN>0ZJB001</ASIN>
            <OfferSummary>
                <TotalNew>0</TotalNew>
                <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
                <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
                <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
            </OfferSummary>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ASIN>9TQ987</ASIN>
            <OfferSummary>
                <LowestNewPrice>
                    <Amount>1000</Amount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <FormattedPrice>$10.00</FormattedPrice>
                </LowestNewPrice>
                <TotalNew>1</TotalNew>
                <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
                <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
                <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
            </OfferSummary>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

So the end result would be (in "pseudo code"):

```
foreach(Items) {
    if(exists ItemId && ASIN) {
        //update span with price
    } else {
        //update span with default text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function callback(xml){
    var itemIds = xml.find('Request ItemLookupRequest ItemId');
    var items = xml.find('Items > Item');

    itemIds.each(function(idx, itemId){
        var item = items.filter(function(idx, item){
            return $(item).children('ASIN').text() == itemId;
        });

        if(item.length){
            //update the span with item.find('FormattedPrice').text()
        } else {
            //update the span with default price
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Arun.  With some modifications it worked.  Changes I made were to "$(itemId).text()" for the return statement, for example, and $(xml).find.  I don't know if this was due to the way my function was or what (I normally work with PHP).  Anyway, thank you for your very helpful response.